# .N differs from length(variable) when variable is used in `by`

Tags: r, data.table

Going around the `data.table` vignette “Introduction to data.table”, the example in section 2 “Aggregations” is just like that

```
ans <- flights[, .(.N), by = .(origin)]
ans
#    origin     N
#    <char> <int>
# 1:    JFK 81483
# 2:    LGA 84433
# 3:    EWR 87400
```

Relacing `.N` with `length` of e.g. "year" gives the same number of rows per group:

```
> flights[, .(length(year)), by = .(origin)]
   origin    V1
1:    JFK 81483
2:    LGA 84433
3:    EWR 87400
```

or

```
> flights[, .(length(carrier)), by = .(origin)]
   origin    V1
1:    JFK 81483
2:    LGA 84433
3:    EWR 87400
```

That was expected. But, when I use `length(origin)`, i.e. the same variable as used as grouping variable in `by`, a different calculations is performed: the result is 1:

```
> flights[, .(length(origin)), by = .(origin)]
   origin V1
1:    JFK  1
2:    LGA  1
3:    EWR  1
```

Are there any explanation for why this happens?

With a more complicated example it could passed unnoticed, so it seems safer to always use the built in `.N` than try to compute counts with the `length` function.

Comment: Seems just recycling happening, like: `data.table(group = "test", value = 1:10)`.

Comment: As for _why_, I think this is a related issue: [Columns appearing in the function in `by=` disappers in j](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1427) (and links therein).

Comment: @Numerari please accept provide answer or provide feedback why you think it doesn't answer your question

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by the fact that variables used in `by` (or `keyby`) argument, or which you are grouping your results, has been already grouped to scalar (a particular group) when accessing them in `j` argument.

There are two related open issue that readers might find useful

- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1427
- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4079